# Find package or somthing like that to draw color in col

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, colors, frontend

I'm working with Reactjs and my client wants to draw the color like the image below.
Could you help me to get a package or solution for that.
The color will darken as the stats go up
and fades as the number of systems points down

Thanks very much and have a nice day

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [rgba](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_rgba.asp) to set the color of background. The alpha color of each container(cell,div,etc) would be a function of its value.

You should first determine how you want the alpha value change according to the value.

1. Determine the min value of your data.
2. Determine the max value of your data.
3. Write a function that maps the value to the alpha value. The following function is linear, but you can make your own function based on your needs or design.

```
alpha = (value - min)/(max - min)
```

4. Choose a color for your columns.

Let's suppose `min = 0` and `max = 500` and you want to set the background to red.

```
value = 0 => rgba(255,0,0,0)
value = 100 => rgba(255,0,0,0.2)
value = 300 => rgba(255,0,0,0.6)
value = 500 => rgba(255,0,0,1)
```

The higher the value goes, the higher the alpha goes.

So you should set `background-color` of each container based on its value. You can set the style directly using javascript, or set an attribute on the container and use CSS to read it or other options.